# ¿por que funciona mi codigo de javascript sin necesidad de usar getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom, metodos

`b1.addEventListener("click", color); function color(){ h.style.backgroundColor = "red"; }`

este codigo funciona sin necesidad de hacer esto `(document.getElementById("h"))` y lo mismo con b1, osea sin llamarlas aun asi javascript las identifica por que?

Comment: Bienvenido. No podemos ayudarte sin reproducir la situación. Mira como crear un [mre].